# Kotlin activity restart

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

How to restart the onCreate after coming back from another activity?
Using below to 
    val intent = Intent(this, WritePage::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

When im finished

> finish()

So i’m back to the previous page. How can i restart this page from onCreate?

Comment: I don't think you can force the activity to restart in that way - that's not how the lifecycle works. Why do you need to force `onCreate` again? If there's specific code you need to run, then consider moving it to `onResume` or another lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is the offical [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) of the lifecycle of an app. If you finish an activity you can only restart that activity by creating a new instance of it. If you want to reuse it you should only pause that activty so you can easily resume that same instance of the activity (as Chris Shaw already mentioned).

Comment: Did this solve your question? If so, please mark this answer as accepted. If not, please provide more context.